# mkdir -p Missing Operand when running rubber:config

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rubber

I am getting following error while running cap rubber:config.  Hope someone can give me directions.

Here is the command I am running: **bundle exec rubber "config"**
As you can see, it is complaining about missing operand for the 'mkdir -p' command at the end.

```
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/common/crontab
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/common/gemrc
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/common/ntp-sysctl.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/common/ntp.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/common/rsyslog.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/common/rubber.profile
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/common/ruby.profile
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/collectd/collectd-ping.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/collectd/collectd.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/collectd/filters.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/collectd/graphite-collectd.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/collectd/thresholds.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/collectd/types.db
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/haproxy/haproxy-base.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/haproxy/haproxy-default.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/haproxy/haproxy-passenger.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/haproxy/monit-haproxy.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/haproxy/syslog-haproxy.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/haproxy/syslogd-default.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/monit/monit-default.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/monit/monit-postfix.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/monit/monit.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/passenger_nginx/application.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/passenger_nginx/crontab
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/passenger_nginx/monit-nginx.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/passenger_nginx/nginx
Rubber[INFO]: Transforming /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/passenger_nginx/nginx.conf
Rubber[INFO]: Transformation executing post config command: function error_exit { exit 99; }; trap error_exit ERR
mkdir -p 
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
Rubber[INFO]: 
Rubber[ERROR]: Transformation failed for /mnt/publify-production/releases/20130814042309/config/rubber/role/passenger_nginx/nginx.conf
Rubber[ERROR]: Post command failed execution: function error_exit { exit 99; }; trap error_exit ERR
mkdir -p
```

Comment: Hey, I'm struggling with this issue as well, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the nginx_log_dir setting added to your rubber-passenger_nginx.yml file like I did. Pop that file open and add it:

```
nginx_log_dir: /mnt/nginx/logs
```

I hope that helps you.

EDIT:

See the accepted pull request that fixes this issue: [Github Pull Request](https://github.com/rubber/rubber/pull/392)